# Confirm accepting a payment!

Tags: paypal, payment, banking, onlinebanking

I want to make a web application were people are paying money (for example through mastercard/visa/paypal etc.).

My question is: can it somehow be made that the money transfers are made only after a longer period when a condition is met in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

What's your real question?

You have a multi-step workflow with money changing hands after many steps.  That's pretty standard for all shopping-basket sites.